# MySQL Independently select last value across multiple columns which isn't null

Tags: mysql, select

Here's an example dataset that I'm dealing with:

```
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| id |  a  |  b  |  c  |  d  |
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  1 |  1  |     |     |     |
|  2 |     |  2  |     |     |
|  3 |     |     |     |     |
|  4 |     |     |     |  4  |
|  5 |     |  3  |     |     |
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

I want to select the bottom-most values. If this value has never been set, then I'd want "null", otherwise, I want the bottom-most result. In this case, I'd want the resultset:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  a  |  b  |  c  |  d  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  1  |  3  |     |  4  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

I tried queries such as variations of:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `a`,`b`,`c`,`d`
FROM `test`
WHERE `a` IS NOT NULL
AND `b` IS NOT NULL
AND `c` IS NOT NULL
AND `d` IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY 'id' DESC LIMIT 1;
```

This didn't work.

Would I have to run queries for each value individually, or is there a way to do it within just that one query?

Comment: what do you mean "bottom-most" maximum value or greater id? or sth else?

Comment: Hint: `SELECT MAX(id) FROM test WHERE a IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: greatest ID, where the value is not null.

Comment: @Raptor So this is only possible using multiple queries per column? eg, `SELECT a FROM test WHERE a IS NOT NULL ORDER BY id DESC` `SELECT b FROM test WHERE b IS NOT NULL ORDER BY id DESC` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are OK with changing type to a char, you can do this:

```
SELECT substring_index(GROUP_CONCAT(a),',',1) as LastA, 
       substring_index(GROUP_CONCAT(b),',',1) as LastB, 
       substring_index(GROUP_CONCAT(c),',',1) as LastC, 
       substring_index(GROUP_CONCAT(d),',',1) as LastD
FROM
(
  SELECT id, a, b, c, d
  FROM MyTable
  ORDER BY id DESC
) x;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1acea/4)

Notes:

- The intermediate derived table is needed as the input to `GROUP_CONCAT` needs to be ordered.
- After compressing the rows with `GROUP_CONCAT` (using the default comma delimiter), we then scrape out the first column with `substring_index`. `substring_index` on NULL returns NULL, as required.
- If you need the resultant columns to be INT, you'll need to cast each column again.

Comment: Seems to work great. The type as a char is fine; however, would this still work for larger tables?

Comment: Yes, it should work. The maximum output of GROUP_CONCAT is [1024 bytes by default](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len). Beyond this limit, the output is [simply truncated](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) which is fine for our purposes - we just want the first non-null value. What you can also do is apply a sensible `LIMIT()` to the derived table query, IFF you know more or less where the last row is expected?

Comment: @ieatpizza Just to confirm, my answer is for the bottommost non-null value as determined by the `id` column. If you want the largest non-null value irrespective of order, the query is simply `SELECT MAX(a), MAX(b), MAX(c), MAX(d) FROM MyTable` - nulls are eliminated from aggregates unless otherwise instructed.

Comment: Alright. I've never actually used derived tables before; I had always just assumed that if the database had to create/hold this entire derived table for each time I ran the query, regardless of what I did with the result, at best it'd be very slow.

Yep the order matters.

Comment: @ieatpizza you are right, the select can be expensive - LIMIT will help here. [Another example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/992f2/1) of `GROUP_CONCAT` truncation, so this isn't going to the problem.